# how to disable retracing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have code which optimize a function using Newton Rapson approach with Hessian.

```
import tensorflow as tf

var = tf.Variable([3., -1., 0., 1.], dtype=tf.float32, name="var")

for i in range(10):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
            func1 = (var[0] + 10*var[1])**2 + (5 *(var[2] - var[3])**2) + (var[1] - (2 * var[2]))**4 + (10*(var[0] - var[3])**4)
            g =  tape1.gradient(func1, var)

        gt = tf.reshape(g, [1, 4])
        h = tape2.jacobian(g, var)
        h_inv = tf.linalg.inv(h)
        dot = tf.matmul( gt, h_inv )
        var_next = var - dot

    var = tf.Variable([var_next[0, 0], var_next[0, 1], var_next[0, 2], var_next[0, 3]])
    print('jacobian at ', i , 'step: ', gt)
```

when i put it to the loop i get:

> WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function pfor..f at 0x7f5be4e1bd30> triggered tf.function retracing

i know it happens  when a TF function is retraced because its arguments change in shape or dtype (for Tensors) or even in value (Python or np objects or variables). in my case the argument change is normal.

Comment: I am not seeing any WARNING on Tensorflow 2.4.1. Can you try with latest Tensorflow version and confirm it.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use following workaround to turn off the Warnings

```
import logging, os

logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"

import tensorflow as tf

var = tf.Variable([3., -1., 0., 1.], dtype=tf.float32, name="var")

for i in range(10):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
            func1 = (var[0] + 10*var[1])**2 + (5 *(var[2] - var[3])**2) + (var[1] - (2 * var[2]))**4 + (10*(var[0] - var[3])**4)
            g =  tape1.gradient(func1, var)

        gt = tf.reshape(g, [1, 4])
        h = tape2.jacobian(g, var)
        h_inv = tf.linalg.inv(h)
        dot = tf.matmul( gt, h_inv )
        var_next = var - dot

    var = tf.Variable([var_next[0, 0], var_next[0, 1], var_next[0, 2], var_next[0, 3]])
    print('jacobian at ', i , 'step: ', gt)
```

Output

```
jacobian at  0 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 306.      -144.00002   -2.      -310.     ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  1 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 94.81535    -1.1852257   2.3704371 -94.815445 ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  2 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 28.09341     -0.35116196   0.7023215  -28.093409  ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  3 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 8.324021   -0.1040398   0.20810343 -8.324027  ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  4 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 2.4663827  -0.03082165  0.0616576  -2.466382  ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  5 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 0.73078156 -0.00913089  0.01827012 -0.7307824 ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  6 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 0.21652769 -0.00270531  0.0054124  -0.21652697]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  7 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 0.06415595 -0.00080431  0.00160385 -0.06415619]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  8 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 0.01900928 -0.00023716  0.00047522 -0.01900923]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
jacobian at  9 step:  tf.Tensor([[ 5.6324019e-03 -7.0029724e-05  1.4065549e-04 -5.6322156e-03]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
```